# Micronaut Data Mongo fails to save entity

Tags: mongodb, groovy, micronaut-data

I have some problems using Micronaut Data for MongoDB. When I try to save an entity appears a validation error like this:

> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: save.entity:
> Cannot validate com.example.app.persistence.AccountEntity. No bean
> introspection present. Please add @Introspected to the class and
> ensure Micronaut annotation processing is enabled

But all classes are annotated with @Introspected.

I think that the problem is due to having splitted application in two submodules "core" and "app" and that entity and repository in the "app" module extends some base classes from the "core" module. See example in Github repo.

There is a way to fix the problem? Thanks.

I'm using Micronaut 3.5.5 with Java 17.0.3 and GRoovy 3.0.12 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Sample repo:
[Github](https://github.com/fmonorchio/micronaut-data-mongodb-introspection-error)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you want to be using a `jakarta.persistence.Table` annotation

Try replacing:

```
@MappedEntity
@Table(name = 'accounts')
```

With

```
@MappedEntity("accounts")
```

(for `AccountEntity` and `UserEntity`)

BTW, your repo on github is missing `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`